# PHP users (login registration) without database.. just files

Tags: php, security, encryption

five months earlier i created a websites with a "login/registration" system and i hadn't enough knowledge about MYSQL.. i just had a good idea and i wanted it to be live..
so what i did is that i made a file that contains a serialized array and inside that array the members id,username,password and emails..
i wasn't that dump enough to do that without encryption so i made it like this

```
    ID : reversible manual encryption that uses search and replace to encrypt and decrypt
    Username : sha1 with salt
    Password : crypt
    email :manual encryption that uses search and replace to encrypt and decrypt
```

my website now is functioning properly and i hadn't encountered any problem relevant to this

so is there any possible security issue that i may encounter?
because i'm so busy for the next three months and i don't want to waste my time on something that is not really required..

Comment: If you have made the file storing the information unavailable for users through your web-server, with say an .htaccess file or permissions, I can't see any problems with that solution. The essential part is that the information stays secret. Good luck with your project =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the bcrypt method, that is probably best for passwords. The main thing, though, is not in your encryption, but in whether the file that has all these user data can be downloaded through the web browser, which is likely the case if it's somewhere in your webserver's docroot or a subdirectory thereof, unless you've locked that subdirectory down with the appropriate .htaccess directives.

So check if you can access the serialised data through your web browser in any way. Since you know the file name and location, it should be easy for you. Just because others don't, doesn't mean they won't.

Other than that, the decision to keep stuff in a database rather than in a serialised file is usually not (just) for security, but for convenience, performance and flexibility.

If you can get by with a serialised file then, by all means, use it. As long as it's not accessible to anybody else, you should be fine and in fact will be spared from other attack vectors, such as SQL injection.